# Microsoft LoopBack Adapter Warning while installing Oracle 11g & ORA-12154 error after installing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this message while installing ORACLE 11g Release1 on Windows 7 64bit

before Installing the Oracle DB I created the "Microsoft LoopBack Adapter" & set the adapter to be the first order

Checking Network Configuration requirements ...

> Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
>
> Problem: The install has detected that the primary IP address of the
>   system is DHCP-assigned.
>
> Recommendation: Oracle supports installations on systems with
>   DHCP-assigned IP addresses; However, before you can do this, you must
>   configure the Microsoft LoopBack Adapter to be the primary network
>   adapter on the system.  See the Installation Guide for more details on
>   installing the software on systems configured with DHCP.

And After the installation done I tried to test the connection using SQL Plus I faced this error

-- This is the tnsnames.ora contants

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

MTAHAPC =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MTahaPC.lan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MTAHAPC)
    )
  )
```

-- this is the listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MTahaPC.lan)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Sorry, this is the first trail to install Oracle DB, and I get tired from it

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning indicating that your system has DHCP allocation of IPs. This isn't strictly supported because when the service lookup happens, the TNSNAMES.ora file will have an entry for an IP which may or may not correspond to your system since DHCP would mean the IP may be assigned to other computers when the lease is up.

You can choose to ignore this by clicking on the checkbox next to it to indicate that you want to skip the test.

Comment: Thanx, But is this will affect any thing after that because after finishing the installation & when I tried to test the connection using SQL Plus I had this message "ORA-12154" TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: @MohamedEl-Maghrabi that means either you're connecting to the wrong TNS or the Orcl service hasn't started

Comment: @Sathly I checked the services and it is working
TNS: how to know the right TNS Name?

Comment: that's there in your tnsnames.ora file @MohamedEl-Maghrabi

Comment: @Sathly I tried tnsping MTAHAPC.lan and I have this message "


C:\>tnsping MTAHAPC.lan

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on 20-FEB-2
012 14:32:44

Copyright (c) 1997, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTO
COL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.68)(PORT=1521)))
OK (0 msec)

Comment: Please edit your question and add contents of `tnsnames.ora` and `listner.ora` file present in `E:\ORACLE\Oracle_Base\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin` folder. Also, my name is **Sathya** not whatever it is that you've typed. @MohamedEl-Maghrabi

Comment: Really I am sorry about typing your Name wrongly Sathya
I added the contains of the 2 files in the question as you asked

Comment: the tns name / "host string" under SQl*Plus will be `MTAHAPC` @MohamedEl-Maghrabi

Comment: Right & what can i do to connect to the Oracle DB?
because I just open SQL Plus And Type UserID: SCOTT "the built in account" and the password & I got this error
Sorry again about this foolish questions but it is first time to install & work with Oracle DB

Comment: user id will be `scott` password will be the password you chose when you performed the install & hoststring will be `MTAHAPC` @MohamedEl-Maghrabi If this doesn't work, edit `tnsnames.ora` and change `HOST=MTahaPC.lan` to `localhost`.

Comment: where I should enter the "hoststring"
when I open the SQL Plus I found only "Enter user-name" so I typed SCOTT after that it asked about the password when I typed it I faced the mentioned error & I tried to change the HOST in tnsnames.ora and tried & I still have the error

Comment: @MohamedEl-Maghrabi try scott@MTAHAPC when asked for username. Otherwise use [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: it is not working also, I think I will try the SQL Developer and see what happen
Thanx for your effort

Comment: I tried the SQL Developer & I got this error also

Status : Failure -Test failed: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: @MohamedEl-Maghrabi please edit your question & add the latest contents of tnsnames.ora & listner.ora files